# Form-Plugin for DokuWiki

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm evaluating the Wiki-System DokuWiki and like it very much.
What I'm missing is the possibility to create SQL snippets like in TWiki.
I'd like to embedd some controls in the text for being able to create kind of formulars. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Bureaucracy plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:bureaucracy), it does what you need.

Further you can add [data plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:data) to make it even more flexible.